# How to use different mailboxes (sent folder) in Outlook for Mac

Tags: macos, email, ms-office, exchange

I am a network administrator and have come across a problem regarding MS Outlook for MAC. The user has their own account already added to their outlook. They have requested that a group mailbox could be added. I set it up in exchange gave the appropriate permissions, then added the mailbox in the user's outlook. It worked fine, they can send with the alias that was created. The only problem is, when they send from the alias (Lets call it design@domain.com) It shows up in their personal (user@domain.com) sent items folder. Is there a way to change it so that it shows up in the design@domain.com's sent items folder?

Comment: Which version of Exchange are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client-side, no.

On the server-side, there are updates to [Exchange 2007](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972148) and [Exchange 2010](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2632409) that address this.

If there is some reason that you can't update your Exchange server, then you could get around this on the client-side with a bit of work.  If the senders BCC the design@domain.com address when sending mail from that account, you could have a server-side rule on design@domain.com which automatically moves mail that is BCCed to design@domain.com to the Sent Items folder.  This isn't by any means a perfect solution, but it might work until you can update your Exchange server.

Comment: I'm not able to update the server at the moment but I will try your second solution. Thanks very much.